# Alternative proofs of the fact that "The product of first $k$ primes is greater than or equal to the sum of $(k + 1)$th and $(k + 2)$th primes"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers

The above theorem that "The product of first $k$ primes is greater than or equal to the sum of $(k + 1)$th and $(k + 2)$th primes" can be proven easily by invoking the fact that every positive integer can be expressed as a sum of two relatively prime positive integers, each of them being greater than $1$.

But I was wondering whether there could be other another elementary proof without using this fact (I find my own very unsatisfactory), I would be thankful if you could provide other proofs or at least hint at some probable proofs, so that I may be able to get a better understanding of the theorem and its implications.

Comment: Please include your question in the post itself instead of the title only.

Comment: As stated, the theorem is false. $2\cdot 3 <5+7$

Comment: Well the condition for expression as a sum of relatively prime numbers each greater than one holds for all integers greater than 6  and 2×3 = 6, you might have taken a while to think before discrediting the veracity of this proposition, and down voting.

Comment: The proof relies on decomposing the product side as a sum.

Comment: If $P$ is the product of the first $k$ primes, it is enough to show $P>p_{k+1}+1$, since $p_{k+2}$ is less than or equal to any prime factor of $P-p_{k+1}$.